# Ada Maps: no visible subprogram matches the specification for "="

Tags: ada

I've been using Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hased_Maps to create my own custom hashed maps, and it worked quite well until I tried to use a vector as the element type. Here is an example of the problematic code:

```
   package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Element_Type => Unbounded_String, Index_Type => Natural);
   subtype String_Vector is String_Vectors.Vector;

   package Positive2StringVector_HashMaps is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps --Compiler fails here
     (Element_Type    => String_Vector,
      Key_Type        => Positive,
      Hash            => Positive_Hash,
      Equivalent_Keys => Positive_Equal);
```

Basically, I cannot `Positive2StringVector_HashMaps` package, because the compiler comes up with:

```
no visible subprogram matches the specification for "="
```

From what I understand, it isn't finding the equality operator for the `String_Vector` , am I correct? If I am, what is the proper way of implementing it? And if I'm not, what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need to implement

```
function “=“ (L, R : String_Vectors.Vector) return Boolean
```

yourself, because there already is one in `String_Vectors`; see ALRM [A.18.2(12)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p12). So you write

```
package Positive2StringVector_HashMaps is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps
 (Element_Type    => String_Vector,
  Key_Type        => Positive,
  Hash            => Positive_Hash,
  Equivalent_Keys => Positive_Equal,
  “=“             => String_Vectors.”=");
```

By the way, is there some reason you used `Ada.Containers.Vectors` on `Unbounded_String` rather than `Indefinite_Vectors` on `String`? (wanting to change the length of a contained string would count as a Good Reason!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As for your question, I must be honest and admit that Strings in Ada were driving me insane, due to the fact they are "immutable", so I've just used Unbounded_String throughout my entire program. I know Ada gurus hate this, but I'm sorry, maybe I'm showing my ignorance here, but I just cannot see the point of a string variable that cannot be changed. Might as well be a constant...

Comment: Strings aren’t really immutable, of course, but in any reasonable application being unable to change the *length* means they might as well be